# Drupal 7 - Is it possible to have two AJAX fields on one form

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms, drupal-ajax

Is it possible to have two fields on one form that are each populated by a different AJAX callback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have as many ajax fields as you want.